# How to find all types of a movie

Tags: mysql, sql

My mind stacked really , I study databases (MySQL) for my school and I stacked for some reason.

Well , lets say I have one database, and these 3 tables with the following columns:

```
[movies_info]
movie_ID
movie_name
movie_age
movie_director

[movies_types]
movie_ID
type_ID

[types]
type_ID
typeName
```

And for example , I want to see what type (by name , so by `typeName`) is for example movie Harry Potter ( so movie_name = Harry Potter). What sql command should I execute?

Comment: use joins b/w [movies_info] and [movies_types]

Comment: which version you using mysql 5.5.32 or else?

Comment: i use mysql , the new . 5.5.32

Comment: Can you show your query till now, we will help to resolve that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not MySQL guy, so here is the same MS SQL Version. You can take this as sample/concept,then convert it as your need;

```
SELECT t.typeName, MI.*
FROM movies_info MI INNER JOIN movies_types MT ON MI.movie_ID = MT.movie_ID
     INNER JOIN types T ON MT.type_ID = T.type_ID
WHERE movie_name = 'Harry Potter' ;
```

I think, you need this, you need something else, let me know.